# RMI Printing Report in client printer

Tags: java, crystal-reports, rmi

I'm using Java RMI Server - Client Solution, client will request report from server, server in turn will generate the report using Crystal Report.
Now, I need to print the report on the client printer.

Do I need to send the file from the server to client the doing the print.
Or there is a solution to make the server print on the client printer directly.

Comment: No, you need to send the data to the client.